# Binary Tree Insertion Error

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I looked at several BST Insert articles but none of them were structured the same as mine or encountered the same problem.

My problem is my Binary Tree isn't being built correctly.  It's really strange because I'm copy+pasting most of the code from a previous project where it works fine, the only difference is the data the nodes contain, and the condition for looping through the tree uses strcmp rather than integer comparison.

This is my insert function:

```
//insert parameter node data into a Binary Tree
TreeNodePtr insertNode(BinaryTree bst, Record d)
{
    //if root is null insert into root
    if(bst.root == NULL)
    {
        bst.root = (TreeNodePtr) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
        bst.root->data = d;
        bst.root->left = NULL;
        bst.root->right = NULL;
        return bst.root;
    }

    //we need to traverse the tree so declare a pointer "curr" to do so
    TreeNodePtr curr = (TreeNodePtr) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    curr = bst.root;

    //loop until we find an appropriate empty space or a match (no duplicates)
    while (strcmp(d.lastName, curr->data.lastName) != 0)
    {
        if (strcmp(d.lastName, curr->data.lastName) < 0)
        { // if left
            if(curr->left==NULL) 
            {
                curr->left = (TreeNodePtr) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
                curr->left->data = d;
                curr->left->left = NULL;
                curr->left->right = NULL;
                return bst.root;
            }
            curr=curr->left;
        }
        else if (strcmp(d.lastName, curr->data.lastName) > 0)
        { // try right
            if(curr->right==NULL)
            {
                curr->right = (TreeNodePtr) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
                curr->right->data = d;
                curr->right->left = NULL;
                curr->right->right = NULL;
                return bst.root;
            }
            curr=curr->right;
        }
    }

    return bst.root;
}
```

Here is the code in the main function which uses the insert function to build the tree (note that records is a correctly populated array, each index containing one node's data):

```
//declare BST and build it
BinaryTree phoneTree;
phoneTree.root = NULL;

for (int i=0; i < sizeof(records) / sizeof(Record); i++)
{
    Record tmpRecord;
    tmpRecord.firstName = records[i].firstName;
    tmpRecord.lastName = records[i].lastName;
    tmpRecord.phoneNum = records[i].phoneNum;
    phoneTree.root = insertNode(phoneTree, tmpRecord);
}
```

And for reference, here are the tree structs:

```
//phone data record struct
typedef struct
{
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    char *phoneNum;
}Record;

//define the tree node which contains the data
typedef struct treeNode
{
    Record data;
    struct treeNode *left,*right;
}TreeNode,*TreeNodePtr;

//define binary tree struct
typedef struct
{
    TreeNodePtr root;
}BinaryTree;
```

I've been staring at the program that works and comparing it to this program for about 5 hours now and I can't figure out what's going wrong.  I know the tree isn't populated correctly because if i try to print phoneTree.root->right.data or phoneTree.root->left.data attributes, the program crashes.  In the program I'm borrowing the code from, these attributes are printed without error.  The root is still inserted correctly and it's attributes can be printed.

Any insight as to what I'm doing incorrectly is greatly appreciated.

Comment: first caution I see is how you are allocating memory (although pretty sure is is not root cause, could be an issue)  In lines like:  `curr->left = (TreeNodePtr) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));` you should not cast the output of malloc() et. al.

Comment: malloc returns a void pointer, in c you can assign a void pointer to another pointer type without error, but if you compile the same code with a c++ compiler the cast will be required.

Comment: "if i try to print phoneTree.root->right.data or phoneTree.root->left.data attributes, the program crashes."  Have you considered that the problem might then be in your printing code (which you did not present), rather than in your tree insertion code?

Comment: It is not the reason for your problem, but your code does have a significant memory leak.  The `insertNode` function allocates memory and assigns its address to variable `curr`, then immediately overwrites that only pointer to the allocated memory with a different value.

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++.  It is not correct to cast output of malloc in C.  There is no indication at all from syntax that it will be compiled in C++.

Comment: @ryyker it's not incorrect to cast the pointer either,  in fact the compiler is doing it implicitly for you anyways.  Many programmers prefer to make the cast explicit because it is required in c++. This is just a red herring and not really relevant to the question anyways.

Comment: "I've been staring at the program that works and comparing it to this program for about 5 hours now and I can't figure out what's going wrong". That's not the best way to debug a program. Use a debugger to step through your program, look at variable values at various stages to see where things go wrong. Learning debugging skills will gain you much more in the long run than having someone else solve this one problem for you.

Answer (score 3):

There is one definite mistake, which could be causing you problems. You need to pass "bst" by reference, so that the function can modify "bst.root". Try rewriting the function as:

```
 TreeNodePtr insertNode(BinaryTree* bst, Record d)
```

and use "bst->" in place of "bst."

You said that it worked with integers. Now that may be a clue to another mistake. Your record contains only pointers to strings. Do these pointers remain valid throughout the lifetime of the tree? Maybe you need to make copies of the strings within the record.

Couple of other minor things:

```
//we need to traverse the tree so declare a pointer "curr" to do so
TreeNodePtr curr = (TreeNodePtr) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
curr = bst.root;
```

malloc is redundant here, the result is immediately overwritten.

And:

```
    }
    else if (strcmp(d.lastName, curr->data.lastName) > 0)
    { // try right
```

you can replace this with "} else {" as you already did this strcmp operation.

Comment: Even with replacing the final "else if" with plain "else", the function will often perform the same `strcmp()` call twice.  It would be more efficient to perform the call once and store the result in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the great tips, they've all contributed to my understanding of memory management in C.

Strangely, I found the problem is actually rooted in my array for loop.  I found the method of using sizeof(array) / sizeof(arraydatatype) from multiple sources on the internet and this site so I attempted it, but it doesn't work the way I tried.  In:

```
for (int i=0; i < sizeof(records) / sizeof(Record); i++)
{
    Record tmpRecord;
    tmpRecord.firstName = records[i].firstName;
    tmpRecord.lastName = records[i].lastName;
    tmpRecord.phoneNum = records[i].phoneNum;
    phoneTree.root = insertNode(phoneTree, tmpRecord);
}
```

I replaced "i < sizeof(records) / sizeof(Record)" with just"i < 3" (array should only have 3 elements at this point), and everything worked as it should.  It's a really dumb source of the problem, but funny that despite all the answers provided none mentioned it :p

Since we're already here, can anyone explain why that was going wrong / how to properly loop through an array in such a manner?

Comment: Where is `records` defined? Note that there's a very big difference if it's an array or a pointer (including an array that decayed to a pointer when passed as an argument). The first would work, the second won't

Comment: It is defined in main and then passed into a function to populate it from a text file, so I suppose it would decay to a pointer?  Keeping all the code within the main method will preserve it as an array and thus sizeof(records) / sizeof(Record) will work? Because copying "loadFile" function which populates the array into the main method doesn't change anything, it still only works if the condition is "i < 3".

Comment: I don't know what loadFile does, but the first part should explain why you see this problem. Naturally, the solution isn't to avoid functions, but rather to find a way to determine the array size. If the array is constant size (not a VLA) it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: > Since we're already here, can anyone explain why that was going wrong / how to properly loop through an array in such a manner?


In cases like this, the usual approach is to have a final record in the array in which all the fields are set to some invalid value, e.g. NULL. This is called a "sentinel". Your loop detects the invalid record and stops at that point, e.g. "for (i = 0; records[i].firstName != NULL; i++)"